# How to get DB query result without extra comma being added when using robot framework

Tags: database, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework to connect to the database. The connection query is:

```
${Result_Intake}= | Query | SELECT Use_Intake_Datapage_Flag FROM smCase_Type WHERE Case_Type_Code = 'VR'
Log ${Result_Intake}
```

The Problem is that the result that returned with is like `[(False,)]`. There is extra comma `,` added in the end of the result, and hence not able to make decision based on the result received from the query.

Comment: Got the answer . I have to Access it like ${Result_Intake[0][0]}. It seems to be a 2 dim Array.

Comment: the comma isn't in the data, it's only in the string representation of the data. This is how python represents a tuple that has only one value.

Answer (score 3):

Got my answer. I have to Access the database like:

```
${Result_Intake[0][0]}
```

It seems to be a 2 dim Array